# hierarchical select based in taxonomy

Tags: 7, webforms, taxonomy-terms

I have used the Simple hierarchical select and hierarchical select module long time ago, but now I need that functionality for a webform, I have a list of taxonomy terms with all the states and cities of my country organized

I know that with webform conditionals I can create each condition separately but that would be very tedius, is there a way of create the hierarchical select functionality based on my taxonomy terms for my webforms?

Comment: I have not seen any ready module for that but you could try to form alter the webform component, have a look at http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3680/how-to-create-a-hierarchical-select-field-for-a-drupal-7-form-using-form-api

Comment: @PontusNilsson That link is dead

Comment: The link works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use contrib module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_shs to make terms in hierarchical select.